# Tryparse and IsDefined for Enum in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

All, I have to do is:

Find out whether a string is a valid Enum element and if so, return status.

something like, If I have an enum say Enum_Test which in turn consists of red, blue , green as its value.

Now, if blue is the element to be verified, I use something like

```
Enum_Test evalue;
if(Enum.TryParse(string_Verify, true, out evalue))  
{
        return true;
}
```

Or otherwise I have an another option,

```
if( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enum_Test), string_Verify))
{
        return true;
}
```

What is the advantages and pit falls in the above methods ?

Comment: Its actually meant for telling whether the string value is a valid Enum element or not..

Comment: They both deceptively use Reflection internally. `Enum.IsDefined` more-so.

Comment: Beware that  `Enum.TryParse<T>` returns true for numeric strings (like `"123"`) as long as the number is within the range of underlying type of `T`, even if  `T` has no value that corresponds to `123`. Whereas `Enum.IsDefined` is much more strict, in that it not only doesn't handle cases like `"123"` but also throws if the value you pass is either not a string or not the exact enum type. For more robust solution that you will have to use a combination of both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Advantage of the first method**: It's case insensitive: If you get `blue`, and there's an enumeration member `Blue`, all will be fine.

**Advantage of the second method**: It's self-documenting: You don't really want to *parse*, you want to check whether there is an enum value *defined* with a given name. So, in the second case, the name of the method more closely matches your intent.

That said, if you want both advantages, use the first method and encapsulate it into a well-named method (e.g. `IsEnumDefinedIgnoreCase`).

Comment: In MSDN, enum.tryParse is said to be case-sensitive. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx > `If value is the string representation of the name of an enumeration value, the comparison of value with enumeration names is case-sensitive`

Comment: @BeytanKurt: In general, you are right, but the OP uses the [`(string, bool, TEnum)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) and passes `true` for `ignoreCase`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification, I missed it out.

Answer (score 10):

Also, be aware that the TryParse method will return true if you pass it an string including a number, e.g. "123".

Answer (score 1):

In first case if your parsing is successful then you will get the enum value in `evalue`. You are also passing `true` for ignore case parameter, so the comparison will ignore the case of the string. The way you have it now, it would return `true` in success and discard the value in `evalue`.

In 2nd code you are only checking if the enum is defined or not.